# Itemclick event in listview with section

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

i m developing application in which my activity contain listview with section...

when i click on listview it gives me position on listview but i want to know position of item within particular section..

i suppose to know the name of the header as well as positiion  of item on click event...

can any one suggest me what to do???

Comment: Your going to need to provide some code, I'm not sure how you have implemented sections to answer this.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us more about the sectioned ListView you're using. This isn't built into the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onItemClickListener` instead of `OnCLickLisnter`. For example:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // do whatever you want
            }

        });
```

Comment: thanks buddy....my problem is solved...do u know how to fetch all images from gridview on itemclick listener..?